# Post content to Facebook Wall

Tags: social-network, nodes

I'm using Drupal 7.

I've an Article content type, when it gets published it needs to be posted into my Facebook Wall. How can I implement this process? I've searched the drupal.stackexchange.com but I couldn't find the right way to do. Can you put me through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Drupal for Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb) module. It's not the easiest thing to setup in the world, you'll have to read the docs carefully. One of the features is publishing site content to a Facebook Wall.